# Some questions about Facebook Score API

Tags: facebook, api

I use Score API to upload score to facebook and expect something like [this](http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/cm_passing.jpg), or [this](http://developers.facebook.com/attachment/cm_high_score.jpg) shown on the user's wall.
But nothing happen in the end.

Code below is developed with Facebook Android SDK

```
public void PostScore(int RequestID, int Score) {
    Bundle Parameters = new Bundle();
    Parameters.putString("score", String.valueOf(Score));

    try {
        this._AsyncRequest(String.format("/%s/scores", _UserProfile.getString("id")), Parameters, RequestID, "POST");
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

After invoking method, got response

```
true
```

Check "/USER_ID/scores" with Open Graph Explorer, the result is

```
{  "data": [
    {
        "user": {
            "name": "XXX",
            "id": "###############"
        },
        "score": 1020,
        "application": {
            "name": "XXXXX",
            "namespace": "XXXXX",
            "id": "###############"
        }
    }]
}
```

All I want is to make stories in picture post on user's wall.

Please help me.

Comment: Provide the code you are using. Are there any errors, etc?

Comment: No errors during invoking method. Score uploaded successfully, but nothing is shown on user's wall. It is supposed to generate story automatically, right?

Answer (score 0):

Scores are not automatically published. They are only published under certain conditions, namely when a user:

gets a new high score ("High score story").
pass another friend's score("Passing story").

Answer (score 0):

yeah...score do not get published automatically .

and if they do its only if any user passes the previous highscore via a new one.
Though one could always check that in either the user's activity record or in the user's Game feed tab .

*`Note : one needs to give publish_actions permissions to post the score`*